# how load or link to wordpress post images

Tags: wordpress, image, slideshow

i have slider show for showing images by clicking on it in larger size in post gallery formats
i have this code below
i put in `data-src` this url `http://wpthemetestdata.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/unicorn-wallpaper.jpg` when click on any image directly load this image but i want when put a wordpress function in `data-src` until when click on any images directly show or load tha image

```
<ul id="lightGallery" class="gallery">

<?php foreach ($post_images as $post_image) : ?>

<li class="col-lg-4" data-title="" data-desc="" data-responsive-src="" data-  src="http://wpthemetestdata.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/unicorn-wallpaper.jpg"> 
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
       <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post_image->ID, array() ); ?>
    </a> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem by using this function below

```
echo wp_get_attachment_url($post_image->ID);
```